# Закрывать корректно фрагмент

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть список, в котором при нажатии на элемент списка я закрываю фрагмент

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Данный фрагмент у меня находится в MainAcitivty. Но при закрытии меня перебрасывает аш на SignActivity, которая в приложении явно раньше запускается.
Пробовал закрывать фрагмент следующим образом:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Но так очищалось содержимое самого фрагмента, и появлялся белый экран.

Как можно закрывать фрагмент так, чтоб переходить в MainAcitivity?

Фрагмент вызываю в MainActivity следующим образом:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LanguagesSelectorFragment()).commit();
            break;
}
```

Comment: `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб увы, но ничего не происходит(

Comment: В любом случае getActivity().finish(); закрывает активити, не фрагмент. Из приведённого вами кода не написать как надо фрагмент убрать. Надо его в backstack добавлять. Покажите в вопросе как его добавляете

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос, Вы же это имели в виду?

Comment: Да, это. Добавьте `addToBackStack("test")` перед коммит, а потом используйте код из первого коммента

Comment: @ЮрийСПб выбивает npe в строке где я сохраняю в sp значение 
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); со следующей ошибкой: SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
проблема в том что не может созранить значение, или всё таки в этих переходах?

Comment: Без сооббщения об ошибке помочь вам невозможно. Скорее всего она не связана с фрагментами. Ну и вы не так пользуете префы. У вас локальные для активити, а вам наверняка нужны глобальные для приложения. Получайте их через `PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`